# How do I start a Cron job 1 min after @reboot?

Tags: cron, sleep

I need my script to be executed a minute after each reboot. When I apply `@reboot` in my crontab it is too early for my script - I want the script to be executed after all other tasks that are routinely run on reboot. How might I run the script sometime after reboot?

Comment: Why is it *too early*?  Maybe an init script would be more suitable (by regarding dependencies, e.g. *this script needs networking to be set up first*)?

Comment: my script need be executed after all others, the last in short words

Comment: since your job needs to be executed after everything and since the concept of everything is quite variable (addition of a new autostart@reboot application is not so uncommon), I think it is up to you to place your job into the rc scripts in a way that servers your purpose. Putting your task at the bottom of tasks specified in /etc/rc.local is usually what you want, but depending on your system's startup configuration, this might not hold true all the time. So, test it and see if it works for you.

Comment: Sounds like a case for Upstart?

Comment: Just had a similar situation where I had to use two `@reboot` lines because the first command "took over", although maybe a single `&` could resolve this. Anyway, this worked for me, e.g.: `@reboot mongod --port 27017 /var/lib/mongodb` and `@reboot sleep 60 && /use/bin/node /home/me/server.js`. Had to use the sleep to give mongo a chance to boot up. Maybe there's a better way but this works for now.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Is the script only ever intended to run one minute after boot up, or can it be used at other times, too? In the former case, you can add `sleep 60` to the beginning of your script, or in the latter case, add it to the crontab file:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && my_script.sh
```

As has been pointed out by sr_, though, perhaps you are tackling this in the wrong way, and a proper init.d or rc.d script would be a more robust solution.

Comment: Or use a command line option to tweak the delay (e.g. `script -s X` which would translate to `sleep X` inside of the script).

Comment: Can I apply this to the file taskrunner in /etc/init.d/ ?

Comment: @AndresAngel - I'm sorry, I don't know. I use FreeBSD which doesn't have `taskrunner`, nor, for that matter, `/etc/init.d`

Comment: on my rhel7 sleep doesn't work at all, it sleeps forever & never comes back.

Comment: In my Ubuntu sleep in cron delays the whole boot and the terminal appearance

Answer (score 24):

If you need to execute something after reboot when network will become available, for example, you can write systemd unit that will be executed at required time (of course this will work only on systems with systemd).

To do so create file `/etc/systemd/system/my_script.service` with following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script that requires network
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/full/path/to/my_script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then execute:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable my_script
```

You're done!

Comment: ...for people who don't hate systemd :)

Comment: but it is everywhere, whether you hate it or not ;-)

Comment: It's not on the box I write this comment on right now.  There's this Debian derivative called "Devuan".  ;-)

Answer (score 18):

I would use `at`. As in:

```
@reboot echo /root/bin/do_the_stuff | at now + 2 minutes
# at assigns it an execution time truncated to whole minutes,
# so this means it will execute in 1--2 minutes.
```

... with the added mentioned caveat that if what you really want is to run it after all other things, you should check how to do that in the init that your OS is using.