# Execute a command after 10 minutes of boot

Tags: startup, services

I have a CentOS Server. When the server Boots up I want to execute a command after `10 minutes` of `booting up`. How can I do so?

```
$ /usr/bin/curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X PUT -d '{"RequestInfo": {"context" :"Stop HDFS via REST"}, "Body": {"ServiceInfo": {"state": "INSTALLED"}}}' http://AMBARI_SERVER_HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/services/HDFS
```

Comment: Related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57852/crontab-job-start-1-min-after-reboot if not even a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to write in a shell run at boot

```
at now +10 minutes <<EOF
/usr/bin/curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X PUT -d '{"RequestInfo": {"context" :"Stop HDFS via REST"}, "Body": {"ServiceInfo": {"state": "INSTALLED"}}}' http://AMBARI_SERVER_HOST:8080/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/services/HDFS
echo hello curl > /tmp/curl.log
EOF
```

- a good place, is at the end of `/etc/rc.local`, or `/etc/rcX.d` if your are more familiar with run-level.
- creation time of /tmp/curl.log will tell you if curl ran.

Comment: hi could please tell me with my complete command statement

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in cron too. Just add in /etc/crontab:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 600 && COMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running CentOS 7, you can also use systemd timer units (see `man systemd.timer`). In particular, here, you can use the `OnBootSec=` directive.