# How to set cronjob or unit file to run after reboot

Tags: cron, reboot, systemd-unit

I have created cronjob as 
@reboot root sleep 75 && firefox
but then I test it, but it didn't work.
In /var/spool/mail/root it shows me this

[image]

what I want to archive is after every reboot I want to automatically load my firefox browser.
Want to do it with this with cron job or even with systemd unit file as 
[Crontab job start +1 min after @reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57852/crontab-job-start-1-min-after-reboot)

Comment: I recommend you copy and paste the `text` from the screen instead of a picture of the screen.  The primary reason is that it's considered good etiquette on unix.se, and will help you get answers more quickly.

Comment: You should probably put the desired commands in the startup for your desktop system, KDE, Gnome, etc.  Or maybe X window startup.  You can't really run firefox until X is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after every reboot I want to automatically load my firefox browser.

A cronjob is not the correct way to do so.

For Firefox to be able to run, your X environment (KDE or GNOME) must have already started. Hence the error about `$DISPLAY` mentioned in the last line of your input.

Therefore you need to configure KDE or GNOME to run Firefox upon start.  For instance, here's a related question regarding GNOME: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37957/how-do-i-manage-applications-on-startup-in-gnome-3